# One word other than "inbox" for a temporary storage space

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I use a cloud (Dropbox) folder called "inbox," where I place files (e.g., PDF) until I decide which non-cloud folder I will permanently move the file to.

Is there a word other than "inbox" for such a temporary storage space − similar to "holding cell" (but not a physical space), "cache" (but not hidden file), "purgatory" (but not a place of suffering/cleansing) or "in take". I could not find a word that quite fits; "hold" is, however, boring.  I just want one word meaning to hold something temporarily until I figure out what to do with it or put it away.

Comment: I usually call it “Temp” or some variety thereof. Probably a holdover from back when rummaging through your _Temporary Internet Files_ folder in Windows 98 was a thing.

Comment: Augeas' Stable?

Comment: Speaking from a computer-user pov, I'd suggest "Uploads" or "Uploaded" which are the traditional name for a folder different stuff is uploaded to.  I myself often have a folder called "SortOut" for things - files, emails etc. - that I intend sort and place in proper folders later.  "Audit", "Review", "Classify", "Archive" and "Sort" may be other good names.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun (to replace *inbox, holding cell, cache*, etc), or a verb (*cf* "meaning to hold something temporarily ...")?

Answer (score 2):

How about **pending**? It's an adjective not a noun, but **Pending** as a filename would be easily understandable.

From Dictionary.com:

> [**pending**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pending): remaining
>   undecided; awaiting decision or settlement; unfinished

The OP's request:

> "Just one word meaning to hold something temporarily until I figure
>   out what to do with it or put it away."

That one has a **Pending** file (list, set, etc.) at all implies that one wants to "hold [onto] something".

That **Pending** means *awaiting decision or settlement** implies that one wants to "hold [onto] something *temporarily*", until "[one] can *figure out what to do with it*," i.e., make the awaited-for decision or settlement implied by **pending**.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Back before the interweb, office workers had an "in tray" an "out tray" and a "pending tray".

Answer (score 0):

This is really a matter of preference and there are plenty of titles, such as TO SORT, TO FILE, FOR REVIEW. A good one I resort to for projects is "ACTION."but my personal favorite is simply titled "DESKTOP CLUTTER" created precisely to keep the Desktop Clutter to a minimum.[see sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHz7d.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHz7d.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may call it a ***stopgap***.

> The folder so-and-so is used as a **stopgap** until I decide the folder I
> will permanently move it to.

Cambridge Dictionary:

> **[stopgap](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stopgap)**
> *noun*
>
> something intended for **temporary** use **until something better or more suitable can be found**:
>
> Hostels are used as a stopgap until the families can find permanent
> accommodation.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  I love the word "stopgap" and already substituted "inbox" with this permanent change.  (P.S., Great site!)

Comment: @CitizenKel, happy to help. If you have already decided on the answer that works best for you, please mark it as "accepted".